# Split screen in two div with flex

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm trying to create two centered div, which are seperated by a border like this.

Didn't know how to  do this with flex
I want to have a big container who got exact size of div seperated by a border

[image]

```css
.homescreen-content {
display: flex; 
flex-direction: column; 
height: 100% ; 
width: 100%;
  }
.goto {
    margin-top:20%;
    left:0;
    height: 100% ;
    width: 100% !important;
    background-color: green;
    text-align: center;
}

.no {
    left:0;
    height: 100%;
   width: 100% !important;
    background-color: red;
    text-align: center;
}
.border {
    //margin-top: 15%;
    //margin-bottom: 15%;
    width:100%;
    height:10px;
    background:grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="homescreen-content" scroll="false">
  <div (click)="open()" class="goto">
      <h2>TITLE 1 CENTRED</h2>
      <p>SOME CENTRED TEXT</p>
  </div>
  <div class="border"></div>
  <div (click)="open()" class="no">
      <h2>TITLE 2 CENTRED</h2>
      <p>SOME CENTRED TEXT</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `flex: 1;` to your `divs` - that way they'll have the same size and take up all free space in `container`:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.container {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 1px solid block;
  height: 500px;
}
.box {
  flex: 1;
  padding: 10px;
}
.inner-box {
  border: 1px solid green;
  height: 100%;
}
.divider {
  border-color: red;
  width: 100%;
  border-top-width: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">
    <div class="inner-box"></div>
  </div>
  <hr class="divider">
  <div class="box">
    <div class="inner-box"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to put a clean solution to what the preview looks like, from here you can adjust your code.

The `div#line` can be any block level element, or any element and set it's display block.

`height:100vh` just to fill the entire screen, for the sake of this explanation.

```css
.parent {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.kid {
  flex: 1;
  border: 1px solid;
  margin: 10px;
}

.line {
  background-color: brown;
  height: 45px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="kid"></div>
  <div class="line"></div>
  <div class="kid"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an easy flexbox solution.  If the content inside your two divs are going to be styled the same, you can use the same CSS class for both of them. I've added comments in the code-snippet that might help explain.  I recommend checking out Flexbox Froggy (google it) as an easy and fun exercise that really helps learn the basics of Flexbox.

Hope this helps.

```css
.homescreen-content {
  border: 1px solid black;
 }
 
.goto {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;  /* align as a column and allow wrapping of content */
  justify-content: center; /* centers content vertically */
  align-items: center;  /* centers content horizontally */
  height: 300px; /* fixed height div */
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 20px;
}

.border {
  width: 100%;
  height: 10px;
  margin: 50px 0;
  background: maroon;
}
```

```html
<div class="homescreen-content">
  <div class="goto">
    <h2>TITLE 1 CENTRED</h2>
    <p>SOME CENTRED TEXT</p>
  </div>
  <div class="border"></div>
  <div class="goto">
      <h2>TITLE 2 CENTRED</h2>
      <p>SOME CENTRED TEXT</p>
  </div>
</div>
```